# Diacritic in json_encode and parsing via Android

Tags: php, android, json

I have question about utf8-coded text.

I have in my db text:

```
ščřžřýžá
```

which is OK on web, but when I json_encode() this text I'm getting

```
\u0161\u010d\u0159...
```

When I parse this text with Android, will it be shown like the original?

Comment: Just try it and check what it returns.

Comment: I'm working on web api right now, the android app will be constructed later, so the answer would be great now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It will. Android escapes those characters. For example you can put them in your strings.xml and they will display as expected.